# Earliest attestation of "does/do/did not + verb"

Tags: history, negation

It seems to me that the negation "[conjugated verb] + not" was used in parallel with "[conjugated "do"] + not + verb" in Early Modern English:

> When thou tookest upon thee to deliver man : thou **didst not abhor** the Virgin's womb. (Te Deum, 1549)
>
> Love **looks not** with the eyes, but with the mind, And therefore is winged Cupid painted blind. (A Midsummer Night's Dream, 1595)
>
> And he stayed yet other seven days; and sent forth the dove; which **returned not** again unto him any more. (King James Bible, 1611)
>
> Lo, he **abhors not** the Virgin's womb. (O Come, All Ye Faithful, 1841)
>
> Thou **changest not**, Thy compassions they **fail not**. (Great Is Thy Faithfulness, 1923)

Even today, "be" still uses the former structure.

What is the evolution of these two forms of negation?

Comment: According to *Do-Support in English: Historical Roots and Modern Usage - American University* (pdf), as early as Old English, depending on the function of *do*. You will have to Google that title as I can't get a workable link. The paper includes a nice bibliography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brief answer is:

> The earliest attestation of do in negative sentences is circa 1400. This
> use arose, according to Visser (1969: 1529), "almost simultaneously" with
> the positive declarative, and was an optional form that coexisted with
> examples such as *I went not*. By about 1900, the forms with the negative
> after the main verb were illicit.
> <sub>[Markedness isomorphism as a goal of language change: The spread of periphrastic do in English](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024384185800103)</sub>

The long answer is that people have written entire papers on the origin and development of do-periphrasis and the specific type you're asking about. Here are some links:

- [The use of periphrastic do in Early Modern English
  negative declaratives: evidence from the Helsinki Corpus](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1c04/f73cee8d3959ac8bb0dca778fe8391d3980c.pdf)
- [The Oxford History of English: Affirmative and Negative Do](https://books.google.com/books?id=KuQyRKaoJmUC&pg=PT239)
- [Historical Sociolinguistics: Language Change in Tudor and Stuart England: Periphrastic Do in Negative Statements](https://books.google.com/books?id=9_55DQAAQBAJ&pg=PT126)
- [The rise of do-support in English: implications for clause structure](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2579751_The_rise_of_do-support_in_English_implications_for_clause_structure)

---

Note:

> > Even today, "be" still uses the former structure.

From what I've read, the two are not considered to be the same thing. The only reason *be* can be used like this is because it's an auxiliary/copula. Auxiliaries/copulas can not have [do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) in Standard English.