# Why can't "do" be left out of "I do not like apples"?

Tags: negation, do-support

> I like apples

is good grammar

> I not like apples

is bad grammar. It must be

> I do not like apples.

I'm looking for a concise explanation that I can give to an 11 year old learning English.  I'm a native speaker but I cannot seem to justify the grammar in any better way that "it is so".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I made a slight edit to your question's formatting, to put the statements at issue in standard quotation format; you can roll this edit back if you don't like it, or make your own additional changes.

Comment: Thanks. Was writing on a mobile so formatting is painful. It looks nicer with your edit. Thanks. 

Comment: You can explain to your student that every lexical verb needs an auxiliary verb in order to create its negative. If there is already an auxiliary verb in the verb phrase, *not* can directly be added to it. If there is no auxiliary, the appropriate form of **do** is required to make negative form of verbs. That's all!

Comment: @mahmudkoya "He walked not twenty yards before he spied what was happening."

Comment: If you leave out "do", it becomes ambiguous as to what you left out.  Maybe you left out "am".  I am not like apples (I think of myself more like watermelons).

Comment: @WS2 I think "not" is acting as an adverb modifying "twenty" in that sentence. It's not negating "walked".

Comment: @eyeballfrog I know not, and care not what you say. The [question of verb + not](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103196/verb-not-do-not-verb-what-is-the-gramatical-explanation) was previously debated here.

Comment: @WS2, As @'eyeballfrog' says, in your sentence you are not negating the verb *walked*. Of course you have negated the sentence in of the many ways of doing it. You are just arguing; you know how to negate a lexical verb in standard/modern English.

Comment: @mahmudkoya Which you seemed to me to be saying was impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good question, and I think the answer lies in history. "Do not verb" wasn't always the way things were said. Here's a chart:

> [image]
>   <sub>[The use of periphrastic do in Early Modern English
>   negative declaratives: evidence from the Helsinki Corpus](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1c04/f73cee8d3959ac8bb0dca778fe8391d3980c.pdf)</sub>

The "not+V" form was not as popular as the "V+not" form in eModE, but it was a valid way to say things. The form "Do+not+V" came into being after *do* became used in questions ("Have you any?" vs. "Do you have any?"). "Do+not+V" won out for several reasons:

- English was switching over from SOV to SVO
- It was similar to the existing "Aux+not+V"
- It makes the distinction between object negation and sentence negation clear

  - Example of object negation:

    > But she spoke *not of a lover only, but of a prince dear to him to whom she spoke*
    >   <sub>Cited in the aforementioned paper (E3, CEFICT3B, FICTION,
    >   SAMPLE 1).</sub>

I also wrote [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/389096/191178) about the *Earliest attestation of “does/do/did not + verb”*. The information and sources there are also relevant.

Comment: Wow!! OK I'm still not sure I have a better answer than "it is so" but skimming through the references it is fascinating to see how do support for negation slowly shifted through the centuries.  The question was promoted because the English teacher of my 11yr old daughter marked as _wrong_ her answer that _do_ is there because of negation. Im not sure the answer he was looking for but the true history and real answer looks like it keeps researchers busy and arguing for entire careers :) Thanks. I'll try to convey some of the information to her.

Comment: @brad Your daughter’s teacher was quite simply incorrect. The _do_ **is** there because of the negation: in current English, its sole purpose is to support the negator _not_ in the sentence you give; it has no other function. I might have a word with the teacher about this if I were you.

Comment: The teacher is not a native speaker and I think feels a bit under pressure from the tiny native speaker student. No need to stir things up :). ( We are living in Austria )

Answer (score 1):

You could say **"I like not apples"**.

It would sound rather quaint unless you were using it as irony, for emphasis or for effect. But it would be perfectly idiomatic English.

Comment: I don't think this is idiomatic at all.  I think "I dislike apples" is idiomatic.

Comment: I agree with Xanne--"perfectly idiomatic English" is not the right way to describe "I like not". The grammar is *archaic,* which I wouldn't normally consider to be "idiomatic".

Comment: @sumelic So what? I care not what you think, and know not why you are so hidebound by convention. Previously [debated here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103196/verb-not-do-not-verb-what-is-the-gramatical-explanation)

Comment: The point is that _verb + not_ is still idiomatic (if quite formal) in certain, specific contexts. Verbs of utterance and reasoning (_say_, _speak_, _ask_, _think_, _know_, _believe_, etc.) are generally quite accepting, for example. Most other verbs are much less accepting. The nature of the object (if any) also plays a role. With pronominal objects, acceptance tends to be higher than with noun-phrase objects, so “I like them not” is fine, but “?I like apples not” and “?I like not apples” are both highly awkward. Grammatical, yes, but definitely not idiomatic.